# CDN that bundles npm packages for browsers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, userscripts, bundling-and-minification

TLDR: Does anyone know of a npm package CDN that bundles the Javascript into a non-module js file?

I’m looking to use [this package](https://github.com/refined-github/github-url-detection) in a userscript. It’s a simple userscript, so I’d rather just use the userscript [@require](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#@require) keyword to import it into the single file script.

Generally, you can’t do this for ES Module (and maybe even CommonJS) js files. The normal dist js file for this package has an `export{…}` clause that makes it incompatible with the `@require` keyword.

I’ve been looking for JS CDNs that might be able to bundle the js for me into a form that’s usable in vanilla-JS situations like this one. Here are all the CDNs I’ve found:

- https://unpkg.com/: Seems to just provide the npm entry files straight up. Can’t use.
- https://www.jsdelivr.com/: Also just seems to provide the files without transformation. It seems super popular though; am I missing something?
- https://www.skypack.dev/: Again, just provides the files straight up.
- https://bundle.run/: I think this might have bundled things using Rollup. Dead now.
- https://wzrd.in/: Would have worked; bundled things using Browserify. Dead now.
- [https://bundle.fregante.com](https://bundle.fregante.com/): Properly bundles things, but can’t really act like a CDN.
- [https://cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/): Contains curated pre-bundled files only.

I can probably get away with just bundling the package myself, or (if I feel like tinkering), running my own instances of one of the dead bundling CDNs. But I’m wondering if there is a CDN out there that does what I want, especially since I haven’t found a new major CDN introduced to the ecosystem that’s newer than 2017.

Comment: There's a reason why there are no new CDNs - almost all modern web frameworks require a build step to work. At the very least they require compilation of jsx. Since you need to build your code you can just depend on good-old `require()` or `import` to be the source of your file. Your local `node_modules` directory has become the modern "CDN". With things like htmx and lit-html slowly becoming more popular we'll probably see the return of CDNs.

Comment: Heck, even CSS these days assume you have a build step with tailwind leading the charge of tree-shaking the CSS you deploy so that each app ship with their own custom compiled version of tailwind.

Comment: I never thought of that; that makes sense! Thank you for the context.

Comment: Well modern browsers support ESM out of the box via script tags. It would be pretty ugly tbh but you could, inside the user script, inject an import map and your userland script so you end up with something like https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/import-maps/.